# In Visual Studio how do I copy the 'Full Screen' icon to the toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, toolbar

Under the <kbd>View</kbd> menu, there is a <kbd>[image] Full Screen</kbd> entry that I would like to see on the toolbar all the time. When I enter full screen mode, the icon is automatically placed on the menu bar but then it disappears when I leave full screen mode.

[Menu] <kbd>View</kbd>/<kbd>Toolbars</kbd>/<kbd>Customize...</kbd> doesn't allow me to drag the icon to the toolbar

When I use Eclipse IDE, I can simply double-click the tab to put it into full screen mode - if there was a way to configure Visual Studio to do the same, that would be ideal...

Comment: This was Visual Studio 2013 despite the edits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Customize window navigate to the second tab and find the toolbar you want to edit:

[image]

Use the <kbd>Add Command...</kbd> option and find the fullscreen command in the View category:

[image]

Use the <kbd>Move Up</kbd> and <kbd>Move Down</kbd> to position the button where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

When you go into <kbd>Customise...</kbd>, click on the <kbd>Commands tab</kbd>.

Then click the <kbd>toolbar</kbd> button and scroll to "Standard".

Then click <kbd>Add command</kbd>, then <kbd>View</kbd> and then <kbd>Fullscreen</kbd> and it should be added!